# Populating Tables into Oracle in-memory segments

Tags: oracle, in-memory-database

I am trying to load the tables into oracle in-memory database. I have enable the tables for INMEMORY by using sql+ command `ALTER TABLE table_name INMEMORY`. The table also contains data i.e. the table is populated. But when I try to use the command `SELECT v.owner, v.segment_name name, v.populate_status status from v$im_segments v;`, it shows `no rows selected`.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered this?

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/memory.htm#GUID-DF723C06-62FE-4E5A-8BE0-0703695A7886

> Population of the IM Column Store in Response to Queries
>   Setting the INMEMORY attribute on an object means that this object is a candidate for population in the IM column store, not that the database immediately populates the object in memory.
>
> By default (INMEMORY PRIORITY is set to NONE), the database delays population of a table in the IM column store until the database considers it useful. When the INMEMORY attribute is set for an object, the database may choose not to materialize all columns when the database determines that the memory is better used elsewhere. Also, the IM column store may populate a subset of columns from a table.

You probably need to run a select against the date first